# Socket operation failed - SOCKET_ECONNREFUSED - ClamAV Laravel

Tags: php, windows, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.7

I'm trying to create a validation system to check if the uploaded file has secured, and I use ClamAV, but not work **(Wampserver64)** :(

Give me this error:

> Socket operation failed: No connection could be established because
>   the target computer explicitly denied it. (SOCKET_ECONNREFUSED). Exception (10061)

My Code:

```
// CLAMAV VERFICATION
$validator = \Validator::make($request->all(), [
           'file' => 'clamav',
]);

if ($validator->fails()) {
   return response()->json([
          'title' => trans('lang.OOPS'),
          'html' => $validator->errors()->all(),
          'type_is' => 'swal',
          'status' => 'error'
   ]); 
}
```

I use this package: https://github.com/sunspikes/clamav-validator

I hope for help, Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you'd need [clamd](https://www.clamav.net/documents/scanning#clamd) for that script. there even is a Windows version meanwhile: https://www.clamav.net/documentation (did not know that). still, the daemon and/or socket might be missing on Windows. with `shell_exec()` you could use just any scanner, which runs from the `CLI`... because that script appears to be written for Linux. it's [documentation](https://github.com/sunspikes/clamav-validator#configuration) clearly states:

> By default the package will try to connect the `clamav` daemon via the default socket file (`/var/run/clamav/clamd.ctl`) and if it fails it will try the tcp port (`127.0.0.1:3310`)
>
> But you can set the `CLAMAV_UNIX_SOCKET` (socket file path) or `CLAMAV_LOCAL_TCP_SOCKET` (`host:port`) environment variables to override this.

---

the best option available on Windows might be:

```
$stdOut = shell_exec("C:\...\clamscan.exe C:\...\filename.zip");
```

*unless* there is any `CLAMAV_LOCAL_TCP_SOCKET` `:3310` it could connect to

... because a `CLAMAV_UNIX_SOCKET` won't be available there.